# Inserting range of data from one sheet to the next

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2010

Ok so easy enough I was able to find out how to insert data from one sheet to  another and tally the records

```
Sheets("tempsheet").Range("A1:F10").Value = Sheets("Master").Range("A1:F10").Value
```

but then I tackled the next step on trying to find the next available row and get tackled myself and I'm at a loss to getting it to work. I've check many sites but everything I try I get an error. Then I look at my code and see how it won't work finding the next available row and still post to same A1:F10. So now i'm resorting for online help.

My steps are:

1. Check sheet2 for empty row
2. Copy information from sheet1 to sheet2
3. Tally the number of records.

Comment: Where is your code for tallying the records? Also what kind of values are you tallying? When you say "next available row" do you mean the next empty row? Can you clarify your problem and intended result a little please? :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example:

```
Sub Test()
    DataTransfer Sheets("Master").Range("A1:F10"), Sheets("tempsheet")
End Sub

Sub DataTransfer(SrcRange As Range, DstSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim AvailableRow As Long
    With DstSheet
        AvailableRow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Range(.Cells(AvailableRow, 1), .Cells(AvailableRow + SrcRange.Rows.Count - 1, SrcRange.Columns.Count)).Value = SrcRange.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Excel expert so for a problem like yours, I usually resort to a brute-force approach: As an example, consider two workbooks with a single worksheet each.

In order to copy a block of cells from workbook 2 to workbook 1 I would write a VBA function like:

```
Sub CopySheetFromOtherWorkbook()

Dim exWB1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim exWB2 As Excel.Workbook

Dim exWS1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim exWS2 As Excel.Worksheet

Dim exR1 As Excel.Range
Dim exR2 As Excel.Range

Dim Marker1 As String, Marker2 As String
Dim aRow As Integer, aCol As Integer

Set exWB1 = Excel.Workbooks(1)
Set exWB2 = Excel.Workbooks(2)

Set exWS1 = exWB1.Sheets(1)
Set exWS2 = exWB2.Sheets(1)

Set exR1 = exWS1.Range("A1")
Set exR2 = exWS2.Range("A1")

Marker1 = exR1.Cells(1, 1)
Marker2 = exR2.Cells(1, 1)

MsgBox "Workbook 1 Marker:  " + Marker1
MsgBox "Workbook 2 Marker:  " + Marker2

For aCol = 2 To 11
  For aRow = 1 To 30
    exR1.Cells(aRow, aCol) = exR2.Cells(aRow, aCol)
    Next aRow
  Next aCol

End Sub
```

To do what you are asking to do, all you need to do is add code to test for empty cell and total those who meet your criteria

To actually do this you would want to reference the two workbooks by name and (Possibly) setup code to determine the actual row and col limits.